# LoRa - How to forward packets?

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, lora, lorawan, ethernet

I'm working on a system where LoRa Module 1 forwards packets. In this setup, when a user is connected to Module 2 (linked to an ESP32 board and acting as an access point), and they enter a URL like "google.com" on their smartphone, I aim to have the request travel from the user's device to the ESP32, then to LoRa Module 2, reaching LoRa Module 1. Module 1 is connected to a Raspberry Pi, which, in turn, is connected to the internet. The Raspi should forward the request to the internet, retrieve the response, and send it back to its connected LoRa Module 1. Finally, Module 1 should forward the response back to Module 2, which can then be accessed by the user on their smartphone. The primary goal is to enable users to view basic text-based HTML websites through this LoRa network.

Specific Assistance Needed:
I'm seeking guidance or examples of code related to the following aspects:

Configuring LoRa communication for india.
Handling specific LoRa settings for packet forwarding.
Implementing the communication flow from the user device to the Raspi and vice versa.

Is it possible we keep the distance as minimum as 1 meter for testing between lora modules ?

Comment: This is way too broad for this site. You need to make your own research on the topic and come back with specific questions. Note however that LoRa bandwidth is extremely limited (due to modulation, but also frequent duty cycle limits), and I doubt sending an HTML page over LoRA is viable.

Comment: See if this is of any help to you in settings. 
   https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/lorawan/frequencies-by-country/  As @jcaron said, getting HTML pages maybe too impractical in today's world because they are large. And you will have javascript which will need additional gets, REST queries, etc. May have been possible 15 years ago, in the days of the textual web (pre-mosaic) such as with the lynx web browser. It maybe possible to forward API responses, though.

Comment: IMHO even text-based API responses (e.g. JSON, XML…) are hardly suitable for LoRa. Binary formats (ad hoc or based on things like ProtoBuf) are a much better fit.